# NSTimer target for a function called by multiple ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm working on a Swift App and i'm trying to define a fonction in my ViewController.swift global part to make it available for all of my other ViewControllers.

But the problem is i can't figure out what can i write instead of "self" for my NSTimer target... Tried pretty much everything i know but i can't figure it out.
Could you help ? Thanks !

My code :

```
//Fonction pour afficher les erreurs

func showError(error:String, bar:UILabel){

    switch error {
    case "125":
        bar.text = errors["invalidEmail"]
    case "203":
        bar.text = errors["takenEmail"]
    case "202":
        bar.text = errors["takenUser"]
    case "empty":
        bar.text = errors["empty"]
    case "noInternet":
        bar.text = errors["noInternet"]

    default:
        bar.text = "Oups, Erreur inconnue"
    }



    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: { () -> Void in
        bar.alpha = 1.0


    })

    var timer = NSTimer()
    println(bar)
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.5, target: UIViewController(), selector: Selector("errorFade:"), userInfo: bar, repeats: false)



}

func errorFade(bar : NSTimer){

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
        var daBar: UILabel = bar.userInfo as! UILabel
        daBar.alpha = 0
    })

}
```

Comment: "What I Can i write instead of "self"" why not using self?

Comment: if your others view controllers inherit of this one, they can just override errorFade.

Comment: As an alternative to what @LastMove suggested, in the case where your other view controllers do not inherit from this one, you can add an argument to the `showError` method for the view controller instance: `func showError(vc:UIViewController, error:String, bar:UILabel)` then use that argument as the target.

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're trying to do? Your current call to NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval makes no sense. you're creating a new view controller as the target for the timer. That view controller is a generic UIViewController that won't implement your selector, so it will crash when the timer tries to call it's errorFade method. Furthermore, the view controller is never displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Last Move's suggestion in comments, I overrode my ErrorFade function.